# How to save and read back sharedpreferences with a RESTful web service in android?

Tags: android, json

The current app that I'm creating is using gson to parse and populate a listview via a remotely hosted json file. I have an options menu inside my app that I would like to use that will allow users to select/deselect items so that they will either show (if selected) or not show (if deselected) inside the listview that is shown on screen via the remote json file.

My question is, how do I go about implementing this function? Can I simply use a shared preferences? Is it even possible to hide certain list items while using a json file?

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to figure this out so any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) you could "choose" what is displayed according to some prefs (I would do the filtering on the list of objects you pass to the constructor).
Something like that:

```
public class DbAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Db> {
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    int resource;
    String response;
    Context context;
    //Initialize adapter
    public DbAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Database> items) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        filter(items);
        this.resource=resource;
    }

    private final void filter(final List<Database> input) {
        final String pref = this.preferences.getString("some_key", "");
        for (Database db : input) {
            if (!pref.contains(db.dbid + ",")) {
                this.add(db);
            } 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LinearLayout DbView;
        //Get the current Database object
        Database db = this.getItem(position);
// ...
```

This assumes that the preference "some_key" contains a comma separated list of `dbId` (like `1,5,12,`)

**NB** not tested

Comment: Well I'm already using an array adapter to produce the rows for my listivew. I've been pounding my head against the wall for a week now trying to figure out how to work this into my app. Can you elaborate more on your answer? I'm still somewhat new to android.

Comment: Can you add your adapter to your question? or give a link to the code (pastebin or something like that)

Comment: Here is a pastebin link for my array and a helper class that is used to convert the json to strings. http://pastebin.com/yEq7BN3G

Comment: Thank you sooo much RC! I'll test this out once I get home and I'll update my post to let you know if all went as planned. I really can't thank you enough.

Comment: Okay. I added in your changes to my code last night and it didn't work for me. I must be doing something wrong elsewhere in my code. I'm going to edit in the changes I made and what I'm using for my json and my preferences class to that pastebin link so maybe you, or another member on here can hopefully help me get this going. I again cant even begin to thank you for your help thus far. Getting responses for this issue has been a problem in itself.